# Get average of the numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a shape of `A = (8, 64, 64, 64, 1)` numpy.ndarray. We can use `np.means` or `np.average` to calculate the means of a numpy array. But I want to get the means of the 8 `(64,64,64)` arrays. That is, i only want 8 values, calculated from the means of the `(64,64,64)`. Of course I can use a for loop, or use `[np.means(A[i]) for i in range(A.shape[0])]`. I am wondering if there is any numpy method to do this

Comment: Does `mean` takes an `axis` parameter?  Can it be a tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.mean`s axis kwarg:

```
np.mean(A, (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

The same works with `np.average`, too.